# Wrong encoding when saving forms on Orbeon

Tags: encoding, orbeon, processor

I created my own persistence for SQL Server, and the CRUD works fine, 
BUT I'm having some trouble with the enconding i think, 
i receive the xml text from the XForms like that when i'm going to save something

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3 ...............

metadata                    
application-name w4/application-name                     
form-name usuario/form-name                     
title xml:lang="en"Cadastro/title                     
description xml:lang="en"UsuÃƒÂ¡rio/description              ---------PROBLEM!!!       

metadata             
xforms:instance....................
```

Any ideas how to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to make sure, when you are decoding the XML, to properly deal with the character encoding. How exactly to do that depends on the programming language or framework you are using, but you should:

- if possible use an XML parser and just feed it the bytes (the parser will take care of handling the encoding by itself)
- never assume a default or platform encoding when converting bytes to characters (Java in particular has a number of APIs which, for very wrong reasons, use a default encoding which is platform-dependent)